# RGB pixel values from Pi to Arduino with LED Matrix

Tags: python, arduino, rgb, led

I am using a 32x32 RGB LED Matrix Panel which is connected to an Arduino to output an image of an album cover. This image has 1:1 aspect ratio and has 1024 pixels. I've computed the RGB values for each pixel on the Raspberry Pi. It is stored in an array = [(r0,g0,b0), (r1,g1,b1), (r2,g2,b2),....,(r1023,g1023,b1023].

I would like to send the RGB values of each pixel over to the Arduino so it can output the image on the panel. On the Arduino side, the code would look like this for one pixel:

```
void setup(){
matrix.begin();
matrix.drawPixel(0, 0, matrix.Color333(7, 7, 7));
}
```

where pixel location is 0,0 and the RGB values are 7, 7, 7. How can I feed each pixel's RGB values from the array in the Pi to the code in Arduino? Would a for loop work, and I would need to convert the index of the array to coordinates too. Is this the only way? Thank you.

Comment: How are you going to send it?  Serial port?  You can send over 3,072 numbers in a long series, as long as you have a way to signal "start of sequence".  Imagine, for example, sending "rgb 0 0 0 3 7 3 1 2 1 4 2 7".  Or, if you want to send binary, you could send `127` as a start signal, then 3072 bytes in binary.

Comment: yes, i am doing it over serial, if i push it all out in one line like you suggested, how would the code look on the arduino side? something like 
`b = Serial.read(); // 3072 values 
for (int j=0; j<32, j++){ 
   for (int i = 0; i<32, i++){ 
   matrix.drawPixel(i, j, matrix.Color333(// ? 
   delay(200); 
`

but then how would i iterate through the string of numbers to put into the drawpixel function?

Answer (score 1):

It's just a simple loop.  You read it exactly the way you wrote it.  Remember that there are 3 bits per primary, so you will only be sending numbers from 0 to 7.

```
for( int y = 0; y < 32; y++ )
    for( int x = 0; x < 32; x++ )
    {
        int r = Serial.read();
        int g = Serial.read();
        int b = Serial.read();
        matrix.drawPixel( x, y, matrix.Color333( r, g, b ) );
    }
```

You shouldn't need any delays.

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm... if you send a single white pixel as ASCII (i.e. a string) you need to send:

```
255 255 255<NEWLINE>
```

that will be 12 bytes, i.e. in ASCII:

```
2 5 5 <SPACE> 2 5 5 <SPACE> 2 5 5 <NEWLINE>
```

or in hex:

```
32 35 35 20 32 35 35 20 32 35 35 0A
```

whereas if you just send 3 RGB bytes, that will be.... errr, 3 bytes rather than 12 so it will be 4 times faster, i.e.:

```
ff ff ff
```

I suggest you send 1024 bytes of binary rather than 4096 bytes of ASCII.

Comment: thanks for this, so if i did it this way, i'll send 3 bytes per pixel and this gives 3072 values. how do i iterate through these values to plug into the matrix.drawPixel function? that's my question. matrix.drawPixel takes the pixel coordinate and also rgb values, i'm not sure how to write the loop that iterates through the rgb values and plugs it into the function. thanks!

Comment: You can use Tim's excellent suggestion of a pair of nested `for` loops.